# Wordpress wp_editor featured thumbnail image doesnt show

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i was developing some theme that could create new post on front end. my issue is that when the "add media" has uploaded the photo, everything works well, except that when i set the "set featured image" for that post is not showing on the "thumbnail" when the post is published.

this is the wp_editor code setup:

```
<?php 
$setupev = array(
         'media_buttons'=>1, 
         'textarea_name'=>'post_ne', 
         'tinymce' => true );
wp_editor('content here', 'create_nepost', $setupev); 

?>
```

this is the code i use to publish new post:

```
$the_contnt = $_POST['post_ne'];
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => $get_title,
'post_content' => $the_contnt,
'post_date' => date('YmdHis'),
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_author' => 1,
'post_category' => array(8,5)
);

wp_insert_post( $new_post );
```

is there some code to add-in to get the attachment thumbnail?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `set_post_thumbnail()` function. two things you require for this function are the `$post_id` which is the id you are providing to `wp_insert_post()` and `$attach_id` which is the id of attachment.

`set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );`

you already have `$post_id`, to find `$attach_id`

`$attachment = array(`

```
'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
'post_content' => '',
'post_status' => 'inherit'`
```

`);`
`$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );`
`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');`
`$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );`
`wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );`

Comment: thanks.. so, i have to find the attachmentID from the wp_editor(add media)? and to do so `$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment('','','')` so then the way to get the attachment is to use the `$wp_filetype['type']`?
hmm ill try that